# Build list of Panels for management in C# with Rudimentary Form Builder

Tags: c#, user-interface, panel

I'm working in a form builder that allows me to input *select* custom code. I'm trying to build a rudimentary window manager that shows and hide's panels. I'm using .Visible and System.Drawing.Point in this form OnClick:

```
public void togglePanel(Panel panel)
{
    if(panel.Visible) 
    {
        panel.Visible = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        panel.Visible = true;
        panel.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(panel1.Right + 5, panel1.Top);
    }
}
```

Currently closeAllPanels is just a long list of declarations, i.e. `panel2.Visible = false;`

How can I generate a list of these panels? Can I do so using the GetMembers() method? I'm new to C#, so I'm not really sure which class I'd need to run GetMembers() on to generate that list.

Or is there a much easier way that I'm completely missing?

Comment: are familiar with the `Controls` for example `foreach (Control x in this.Controls){ }` then check `if(x is Panel)` for example .. use a loop to shorten the hard coding of setting Panels Visible Property..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the Panels will always be in the same container, then do something like:

```
        List<Panel> Panels = new List<Panel>(this.Controls.OfType<Panel>());
        Console.WriteLine("# of Panels: " + Panels.Count.ToString());
        foreach(Panel pnl in Panels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pnl.Name + ": Visible = " + pnl.Visible.ToString());
        }
```

You can replace "this" with the name of the container if the Panels are not directly contained by the Form itself.

To get a reference to a Panel "by name" with Controls.Find():

```
        string panelName = "panel1";
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find(panelName, true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is Panel)
        {
            Panel pnl = (Panel)matches[0];
            // ... do something with "pnl" ...
        }
```

Comment: that's exactly what I'm thinking of! Unfortunately, the form builder is so locked down it won't let me build a List of anything, I've thought about using a string[], but that would make the elements un-actionable, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have the Panel name you can get a reference to it using Controls.Find().

Comment: What would that look like?